# How to install centos inside virtual box using iso image

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos-6

I am using oracle virtual box manager

I created the virtual hard disk

In Setting -> System -> Boot order

selected CD/DVD-ROM has the first priority

[image]

And in storage I did this changes

[image]

while starting installtion its giving this error

[image]

What is the mistake here ?

Base system : Centos 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about adding the CD into the virtual machine, if it's a new virtual machine when you first power it on it will run the first run wizard and ask you if you want to install an OS and it will then let you choose the CD / ISO.

You can also use the removable devices options in the Virtual Machines menu.

Answer (score 0):

You unchecked `Hard Drive` as a boot device! That could make it difficult for the machine to, well, install anything. Try checking that box and running again.

Comment: I selected `Hard Drive` also still same problem...